# Importing from torch_geometric_temporal.signal leads to libcudart error

Tags: google-colaboratory, pytorch-geometric

I tried to import `static_graph_temporal_signal` from `torch_geometrci_temporal.signal` in Colab but I got the following error:

```
OSError: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I guessed that it might be related to CUDA, so I attempted to install older version (11.0) but it did not help.

```
! pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu110
```

How do I solve the OSError?